# Python3: auto-generation of variable names for object children

Tags: python-3.4

for a cooling bed representation with different cooling zones (up to 10) I build the following structure:

```
class coolingbed:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._value = value
        self._coolingzone = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'coolingbed({!r})'.format(self._value)

    def add_coolingZone(self, zone):
        self._coolingzone.append(zone)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._coolingzone)
```

Manually I can create a cooling bed by:

```
cb = coolingbed(0)
```

and add 'cooling zones' like:

```
cz1 = coolingbed(1)
cz2 = coolingbed(2)
```

which would be added with:

```
cb.add_coolingZone(cz1)
cb.add_coolingZone(cz2)
```

and verified with:

```
for cz in cb:
    print(cz)
```

That's fine for the beginning, but since this cooling bed representation has the option to specify how many cooling zone there will be, and assign 4 values to each zone, I'm looking for a more automated solution.
In the `pyqt5` gui, there are up to 10 sets of 4 spin boxes which collect the data. Each spin box has it's variable name to respond to.
So the idea is to generate such variable names for the cooling zones in an appropriate manner, depending on how much zones are enabled.

Does anyone have an idea could achieve that? Something like 'cz'+i

cheers,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionarys. You use the dictionary key as the variable name, and the value as the `coolingbed` object.

```
cbeds = {}
for i in range(5):
    key = 'cz' + str(i + 1)
    cbeds[key] = coolingbed(i + 1)
```

Any individual `coolingbed` object can be retrieved by using the corresponding key to index the dictionary. You can use `cbeds['cz4']` the same as if it were a variable name.

Comment: That sounds interessting, I will give it a try. Thx for the effort so far.

Comment: I build the cooling bed structure with it, so I accept that answer, because it's a solution.